# Swift 2.0 - Cannot Subscript a value of type '[CLPlacemark]?'

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to convert my swift 1.2 app to 2.0. I've tried a few fix's that i found on the internet, but it doesnt work.

Error: `Converting to Swift 2.0 - Cannot Subscript a value of type '[CLPlacemark]?'`

Code:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0
        {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error with the data.")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**:

Replace:
`let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark`

For:
`let pm = placemarks?[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Or with updated Swift 2.0 safety :

```
guard let currentPlacemarks = placemarks where currentPlacemarks.count > 0 else {
    // error handling here
    return
}

guard let pm = currentPlacemarks[0] where pm is CLPlacemark else {
    // more error handling
    return
}

self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
```

Comment: I received the below errors when I tried adding your code. Anything thoughts? :                                                                                                               Definition conflicts with previous value                                                   Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLPlacemark'

Comment: That means it isn't an optional and optional binding won't work, isn't needed. Google everything on optionals

Comment: Will do. Its weird, because my code is exactly the same as the original poster so I would have thought it would be drop and replace. Thanks